# Spec on global variables in Javascript initialized from DOM elements?

Tags: javascript

In a very common code example on Javascript event delegation https://javascript.info/event-delegation, I'm confused about where the variable "menu" comes from on line 40 in http://plnkr.co/edit/91Q9jINXlue2fXiB0fAY?p=preview. The variable is passed to the constructor, yet is never initialized. It appears the variable "menu" automatically is created from this div element:

```
<div id="menu">...</div>
<script>
...
new Menu(menu); /* Who initializes "menu".
...
</script>
```

I've been doing Javascript for a long time yet this is really confusing to me. I also am not sure how to generalize this question.

Normally I would do a document.getElementById("menu") to get the div element. Where do these variables get initialized and how can I find out more about variables like these? Is there a spec?

Comment: Aparantly its in the docs https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: Can you provide a name for this globalization of id variables and information on what else is converted to a global variable?

Comment: Having learned a bit more, I've re-titled the question to be more general.

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This variable is generated automatically by the browser and a member of the window element.

The HTML5 standard specifies that the window object must have a property *key* whose value is elem if...

- there is exactly one DOM element *elem* whose property `id` has the value *key*.
- there is exactly one DOM element *elem* whose property `name` has the value *key*. elem’s tag must be one of: `a`, `applet`, `area`, `embed`, `form`, `frame`, `frameset`, `iframe`, `img`, `object`.

The specification can be found here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: Little deeper thanks. Is there a spec for that? Seems everyone in the world already knows about this behavior except me! On the other hand, I know how things go in real life. e.g. (One can never assume anything.)

Comment: I added a link. It's neat to know such things, especially when creating short examples or demos. But you usually shouldn't use it in practice

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll mark this as accepted because it has a reference, which is what I was really looking for (once I had some context about what was going on). Now that I have some keywords for hooks, I'm also seeing a nice discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1620112 with the same question, so this might be a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

I takes the value of the element with the same `id`.

```html
<div id="menu">
```

As [specified by the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#named-access-on-the-window-object):

> ##### 7.2.2.3 Named access on the `Window` object
>
> `window[name]`
>
> Returns the indicated element or collection of elements.
>
> As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code. Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time, as new features are added to the web platform, for example. Instead of this, use `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()`.

Comment: This answer was so similar, not sure which to accept. Sorry Nina, maybe I'll leave the first one for now. Can't remember who answered first. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It comes from this line:

```
<div id="menu">...</div>
```

Browsers expose DOM elements as global variables with names corresponding to their `id` attributes. This is not very good practice though, it's recommended to avoid it as it's pretty error prone and confusing.

Comment: What is the name for this. I always assumed you had to do getElementById()

Comment: @CharlieDalsass You would better use proper methods to select your DOM elements like `getElementById`, `querySelector`, etc. The example in javascript.info is a bad pattern.

Comment: I understand it's a bad pattern, which is probably why I've never seen it before. However, I'd like to understand what this mechanism is and learn more about it.